# Why calling JFrame.pack() after JFrame.setVisible(true) affect the location where JFrame is displayed?

Tags: java, swing

I am compiling and running the following code on Debian 8 with XFCE 4 desktop.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class FrameDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.add(new HelloWorldComponent());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class HelloWorldComponent extends JComponent
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("hello, world", 50, 50);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(200, 100);
    }
}
```

This produces the desired output. The frame is centered on the desktop.

[image]

But when I move the `frame.pack()` statement after `frame.setVisible(true)` statement, i.e. I pack after I show the frame, I don't see the desired output anymore.

```
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.add(new HelloWorldComponent());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.pack();
```

The frame is now displayed at the top-left corner of the desktop.

[image]

In fact, the frame does appear in the center of the desktop very briefly for a fraction of a second. After a split second or so, the frame moves to the top-left corner of the desktop.

Why moving the location of the `frame.pack()` statement change the location where the frame appears on the desktop?

Comment: Because the oracle of Oracle says you pack, then setVisible.  You see what happens when you don't follow the advice of the oracle.

Answer (score 3):

`pack()` makes a call to `setClientSize()` that itself makes a call to `setBounds(x,y,w,h)`

Either way, on my computer, it seems to always be displayed in the top left corner.

---

Here is your explanation from the [JavaDoc about `Window#setLocationByPlatform`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationByPlatform(boolean))

> Calls to setVisible, setLocation and setBounds after calling
>   setLocationByPlatform clear this property of the Window. For example,
>   after the following code is executed:
>
> setLocationByPlatform(true);  setVisible(true);  boolean flag =
>   isLocationByPlatform();   The window will be shown at platform's
>   default location and flag will be false. In the following sample:
>
> setLocationByPlatform(true);  setLocation(10, 10);  boolean flag =
>   isLocationByPlatform();  setVisible(true);   The window will be shown
>   at (10, 10) and flag will be false.

---

## The alternative

if you want the Window to be centered is to use [`JFrame#setLocationRelativeTo(null)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo(java.awt.Component)) (it is important to give it `null` as a parameter).

> If the component is null, or the GraphicsConfiguration associated with
>   this component is null, the window is placed in the center of the
>   screen.

Answer (score 2):

pack() eventually calls setBounds(). According to the javadoc for Window,

> Calls to setVisible, setLocation and setBounds after calling
>   setLocationByPlatform clear this property of the Window.

Thus the window gets repositioned to the platform's default positioning.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `pack()` computes the size of the window, which is required to perform the centering calculation correctly. After setting visible, a call to `pack()` doesn't change window position (but computes the size).